# Make Jquery Capty effect on data came from ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

How can make capty effect on data load from ajax request?
I have some dive in main page and have a load more request from ajax, the capty work fine for main data but not work on data loaded from ajax request and i try to add capty function in ajax result but older div display black screen.

how can i use capty for data came from ajax request?

index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Capty</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.capty.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.capty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.detail').capty({
        height:     163,
        width:      200,
        opacity:    .8,
        animation: 'fade',
        speed:      400
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#more").on("click", function() {
        var ID=$(".box:last").attr("id");
        $.post("ajax/more.html",
        function(data){
            $(".box:last").after(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="holder">
    <div class="box" id="1">
        <div class="detail" name="#info-1">detail 1</div>
        <div id="info-1" class="info">info 1</div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="more">more</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#holder{
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
    background:#CC9;
}
#more {
    padding:10px 10px;
    background:#CCF;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    float: left;
}
.box {
    float:right;
    margin:5px 7px;
    height:163px;
    width:198px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    border: 1px solid #2A5F86;
}


.detail {
    width:198px;
    height:163px;
    background: none;
}
.info {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 178px;
    height: 148px;
    background: none;
    border: 0px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 0px 0px;

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
div.capty-caption {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #222;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    width: 198px;
    max-width: 198px;
    min-width: 198px;
    height: 163px;
    min-height:163px;
    max-height:163px;
}

div.capty-caption a {
    color: #318DAD;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.capty-wrapper {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:198px;
    min-width:198px;
    max-width:198px;
    height: 163px;
    min-height:163px;
    max-height:163px;
    background:none;
}
```

ajax:

```
<div class="box" id="1">
        <div class="detail" name="#info-1">detail 1</div>
        <div id="info-1" class="info">info 1</div>
</div>
```

jQuery Capty - A Caption Plugin - http://wbotelhos.com/capty
plugin also available on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load data from ajax, its elements are not automatically updated with triggers.
When you load your ajax, you need to call `.capty()` on them as well.
Here is an example:

```
function(data){
    $(".box:last").after(data);
    $(".detail",".box:last").capty({
       height:     163,
       width:      200,
       opacity:    .8,
       animation: 'fade',
       speed:      400
    }) ;
});
```

Pay attention to the sequence in the $() selector. The first is really the last.
So selector will find ".box:last" first, and only then will do `find()` in it searching for class "detail"

**=== Edit start ===**

The code after your change will work except that the data returned by ajax must contain unique ids while your ajax/more.html is a copy of what you have in the main body.
Please consider changing ids.
When I changed them myself it worked:
    
        detail 2
        info 2

Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5K3nq/ where I copied your source into.
Instead of calling `$.post()` I have called function `greg()` which returns what your ajax was supposed to return (except it contains my changes.) Scroll the Result window to the right to see your squares.

**=== Edit end ===**

Hope it will help.

PS. In jQuery, use one function that would initialize all elements when whole page is already loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Now, I know the page has completely loded.
    // All initialization comes here.
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i try it before and when use it, capty work for new ajax data but for older data that loaded before the last request, just show blank screen and not show the info div content.

Comment: is there a way to bind ajax data to html dom?